# Scale plot size of matplotlib plots in Qubole Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, qubole

Is there a possibility of increasing the size of the plot plotted using z.showplot() in qubole notebooks.

```
import matplotlib as plt
plt.figure()
plt.bar(pandas_df_hr_sg[:]['hour'],pandas_df_hr_sg[:]['count'])
plt.title('Hourly wise user visits')
plt.xlabel('Hour')
plt.ylabel('Visit Count')
z.showplot(plt)
```

Comment: Try to add `plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 150  ` before showplot.

Comment: And in case you are using a jupyter notebook, the rcParams statement should not be in the same cell as the  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Comment: Thanks for that Kolibril.But this does not seem to work in Qubole notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try setting the plot size by:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
```

This should ideally help in case of Zeppelin notebook in Qubole; let me know how this goes!

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure